# Why AutoLayout is deciding much less with than actual?

Tags: ios, autolayout

Please see image. Actual width is `228`, but why Expected width is `25`? Even when I try to update constraint, it does nothing.

[image]

> I am getting following output in Simulator.

[image]

When I try to add width constraints, as suggested in few comments, I am getting exception.

```
2015-12-25 11:43:21.813 To Do List[1285:24043] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad907143b0 H:[UITextView:0x7fad90841400(228)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad9055a510 UILabel:0x7fad9056e950'Task'.leading == UIView:0x7fad9056e7f0.leadingMargin + 84>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad9055a560 UILabel:0x7fad9056c6b0'Info'.leading == UILabel:0x7fad9056e950'Task'.leading>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad90512810 UITextField:0x7fad9056c8c0.leading == UITextView:0x7fad90841400.leading>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad90512860 UITextField:0x7fad9056c8c0.trailing == UITextView:0x7fad90841400.trailing>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad9055c970 UITextField:0x7fad9056c8c0.centerX == UIView:0x7fad9056e7f0.centerX>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad9055ca10 H:[UILabel:0x7fad9056c6b0'Info']-(53)-[UITextView:0x7fad90841400]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad90578dd0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7fad9056e7f0(414)]>" )

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint  <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad907143b0 H:[UITextView:0x7fad90841400(228)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: If you can add width and height constrain will solve your issue

Comment: probably u did not set the width constraint, u can either set constant width or set the right constraint to the right screen edge

Comment: Please see my edited question.

Comment: @PranitKothari why you have set equal width to text field and text view?

Comment: @MayankPatel because I want them to be equal.

Comment: http://imgur.com/3la7Zca you want like this ? @PranitKothari

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's because you're pinning some views together for width while also setting a leading and a centre constraint. He only option is this to make the views narrow.

Most likely you want to remove the centre constraint and instead pin trailing or width.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have the storyboard set as w Any h Any.  Try changing the storyboard to compact width regular height or any other setting and see if that helps.

Change from this:
[image]
To either of these settings (I prefer to use the latter):
[image]

If that doesnt work, make sure you set a height and width constraint to your textview.  Click control and drag horizontally within the textview and set a width constraint.  Click control and drag vertically within the textfield and set a height constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You get the warning in Xcode because the text field has no text in it, so its intrinsic content size is very narrow and you haven't constrained its width to make it wider.

When you constrain its width to 228, you get an error at runtime because your other constraints don't leave enough room for it to be 228 points wide. Here's why:

> ```
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad90578dd0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7fad9056e7f0(414)]>" )
> ```

UIKit uses a `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width` to constraint a view controller to fit the screen, so this constraint tells me that 6e7f0 is your view controller's root view.

The 414 in this constraint tells me you're testing on an iPhone 6 Plus or 6S Plus, because only those devices have a width of 414 points.

The default `layoutMargins` for a view controller's root view on a 6+ is 20 points on the leading and trailing edges.

> ```
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad9055a510 UILabel:0x7fad9056e950'Task'.leading == UIView:0x7fad9056e7f0.leadingMargin + 84>",
> ```

The leading edge of the “Task” label will be 84 points from the root view's leading edge, so it will be at 104.

> ```
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad9055a560 UILabel:0x7fad9056c6b0'Info'.leading == UILabel:0x7fad9056e950'Task'.leading>",
> ```

The leading edge of the “Info” label will also be at 104.

> ```
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad9055ca10 H:[UILabel:0x7fad9056c6b0'Info']-(53)-[UITextView:0x7fad90841400]>",
> ```

The leading edge of the text view will be 53 points from the trailing edge of the “Info” label.

The “Info” label's intrinsic width, with the default font and size, is 29.

So the leading edge of the text view will be at 104 + 29 + 53 = 186.

> ```
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad90512810 UITextField:0x7fad9056c8c0.leading == UITextView:0x7fad90841400.leading>",
> ```

The leading edge of the text field will also be at 186.

> ```
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad9055c970 UITextField:0x7fad9056c8c0.centerX == UIView:0x7fad9056e7f0.centerX>",
> ```

The text field will be centered. Since its leading edge is at 186, this means that its trailing edge must be 186 points from the trailing edge of its container.

Its container, the root view, is 414 points wide. So the text field's trailing edge is at 414 - 186 = 228.

The text field's leading edge is at 186, and its trailing edge is at 228, so **its width must be 42** (= 228 - 186).

You have set huge margins around the labels (84 on the leading side and 53 on the trailing side). The only “give” in your layout is the width of the text view and the text field, so those are the views that shrink when the views move from the 600x600 template in Xcode down to the 414x736 size of the iPhone 6 Plus.

What you should do is change the 84 to zero, and change the 53 to something reasonable like 8 or 20.